# Why does render_template fail while send_from_directory works in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to modify the following code base:
https://github.com/FloatingOctothorpe/python-kanban

When I change the line in main.py:
`return send_from_directory('static', 'index.html')`

to

`return render_template('index.html')`

I get:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'card' is undefined` -- I even rename the static folder to templates.

What is going on here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided the link to the repository all the code is there

Answer (score 1):

Its not that it cant find your template, its that you must have used `{{card}}` somewhere in your html file and jinja / python cannot locate the variable.

You must be using {{card}} somewhere in the template. Check for it.

`send_from_directory` does just that, send the file as is, it makes no attempt to convert your template or jinja variables to their html couterpart.

When using render_template you must pass in variables as parameters

i.e

```py
@mail.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    card = {"card":"birthday"}
    return render_template('home.html', card=card)
```

There are other methods of passing variables into the template.

You could add a template function which is callable from within your template

```py
from flask import current_app

def get_card():
    return {"card":"bierthday"}


current_app.jinja_env.globals.update(
    get_card=get_card
)
```

Then in the `home.html`

```html
<html>
    <body>
        {{get_card()}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know that render template behavior will require me to pass in a variable in the return statement, however, I am confused why if I changed the line to return send_from_directory('static', 'index.html'), it works, it is still the same index file, I am not passing any variables, this is why I am confused.

Comment: You must be using {{card}} somewhere in the template. Check for it. `send_from_directory` does just that, send the file as is, it makes no attempt to convert your template or jinja variables to their html couterpart, and thus, no error.

Comment: Right, I have checked every where and cant seem to find where that variable is coming from, its not getting passed through the backend and there is nothing indicating in the javascript either.

Comment: Its right here  `<p class="card-text">{{ card.text }}</p>` in this file https://github.com/FloatingOctothorpe/python-kanban/blob/master/static/index.html

Comment: Yes, but where in the code is that variable being passed? In main.py, it just serves the file through the function send_from_directory, it doesnt pass a value, what pass the value to {{card.text}}?